# Android : Clearkey in Media3 / Exoplayer not working for base64

Tags: exoplayer, drm, base64url, android-media3

Working for one Android application to play clearkey content with Media3 and exoplayer.
Build.gradle given below. Problem described below. let me know if more detail is required.

I have two links for Clear key DRM, and **both are working fine in
https://developer-tools.jwplayer.com/stream-tester**

Link 1 is Working in application

Link 1 -->
**https://media.axprod.net/TestVectors/v7-MultiDRM-SingleKey/Manifest_1080p_ClearKey.mpd**

CleaeKey  **FmY0xnWCPCNaSpRG-tUuTQ**

ClearKid  **nrQFDeRLSAKTLifXUIPiZg**

Above link is working in Android Exoplayer/Media3.

Link 2 is not the working case, but does work in jwplayer link given above

Link 2 --> **https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/2433871/sp/243387100/playManifest/protocol/https//entryId/1_pgssezc1/format/mpegdash/tags/mbr/f/a.mpd**

ClearKey **caee457911302478487e6680bf0b3d1b**

ClearKid **a07c5d499dcead0fb416fed5913967be**

Encoded Keys: Tried both with and without encoding for base64url.but no help.

ClearKey   **yu5FeREwJHhIfmaAvws9Gw**

Clearkid   **oHxdSZ3OrQ-0Fv7VkTlnvg**

Below is code snippet :

```
String keyString = "{\"keys\":[{\"kty\":\"oct\",\"k\":\"" + Clearkey + "\",\"kid\":\"" + Clearkid+ "\"}],'type':\"temporary\"}";

LocalMediaDrmCallback drmCallback = new LocalMediaDrmCallback(keyString.getBytes());

DrmSessionManager manager_local = new DefaultDrmSessionManager.Builder()
                    .setUuidAndExoMediaDrmProvider(C.CLEARKEY_UUID,    FrameworkMediaDrm.DEFAULT_PROVIDER)

DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .setDrmSessionManagerProvider(  mediaItem ->  manager_local)
```

And with above detail mediaSource is created with DashMediaSource,passed to player.

build.gradle for this:

```
implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-hls:1.1.0'
```

### Please help with this. Let me know what is missing.

Thanks n Regards,
Dev

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed, Silly though.  there was \n character in final key string..